# How does the itertools "grouper" function recipe work?

Tags: python

From here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

I understand the `zip_longest` call. But I don't get:

```
args = [iter(iterable)] * n
```

If you are gonna be passing an iterable into `izip_longest` later, why bother wrapping the iterable into an `iter()` again? Can't I just do:

```
args = [iterable] * n
```

But it seems that without `iter()`, it just repeats the same iterator n times. But how does putting this in `iter()` change its behavior?

Comment: Because for this to work you have to be zippping the *same iterator*. If `iterable` argument *is* an iterator, then the `iter` isn't required, but it is if it isn't.

Comment: Why would that behave differently from zipping the same iterable?

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/7ce5670a21ca

Comment: Because grouping like this results from the behavior of iterators where they are single-pass. So, think of zip(x, y) doing something like `next(x), next(y)` while there are no `StopIterations`... it isn't the same iterator, say `iterable` is a `list` or something like that, then you simply get the exact same elements, but if you pass a *list iterator*, then it will give you the first two...

Comment: This has been asked multiple times, and I found it hard to give an example that fits into a SO answer, especially one that can serve to explain things to people who may be stuck in different ways or have slightly different questions. So, about 4 years ago, I wrote a blog post about it: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html

Comment: Although in this case, you seem to be stuck on something different than any of those people back in 2013, so that post may not be helpful…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This grouping takes advantage of the single-pass nature of an iterator (as opposed to a mere iterable, which can be iterated multiple time potentially, and using `iter` on an non-iterator iterable  should return a new, independent iterator. In contrast, calling `iter` on an iterator *returns the iterator itself*.

So here is a simplistic implementation of a zip function that takes only two arguments:

```
In [1]: def myzip(x, y):
   ...:     itx, ity = iter(x), iter(y)
   ...:     while True:
   ...:         try:
   ...:             a, b = next(itx), next(ity)
   ...:         except StopIteration:
   ...:             return
   ...:         yield a, b
   ...:

In [2]: list(zip('abcd','efgh'))
Out[2]: [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]

In [3]: list(myzip('abcd','efgh'))
Out[3]: [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]
```

This is pretty much how the built-in `zip` works. Now, what if we do the above with a list as the iterable?

```
In [16]: mylist = [1,2,3,4]

In [17]: iterable = mylist

In [18]: itx, ity = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)

In [19]: itx is ity
Out[19]: False

In [20]: next(itx), next(ity)
Out[20]: (1, 1)

In [21]: next(itx), next(ity)
Out[21]: (2, 2)

In [22]: next(itx), next(ity)
Out[22]: (3, 3)

In [23]: next(itx), next(ity)
Out[23]: (4, 4)

In [24]: next(itx), next(ity)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b6cbb26d280f> in <module>()
----> 1 next(itx), next(ity)

StopIteration:
```

However, if `iterable` is an *iterator*:

```
In [25]: iterable = iter(mylist)

In [26]: itx, ity = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)

In [27]: itx is ity
Out[27]: True

In [28]: next(itx), next(ity)
Out[28]: (1, 2)

In [29]: next(itx), next(ity)
Out[29]: (3, 4)

In [30]: next(itx), next(ity)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b6cbb26d280f> in <module>()
----> 1 next(itx), next(ity)

StopIteration:
```

Finally, note that repition on a sequence never copies the elements of a sequence, so doing `[iter(x)]*n` returns a list with n references to the same iterator, so:

```
In [32]: args = [iter(mylist)]*3

In [33]: args
Out[33]:
[<list_iterator at 0x1040c9320>,
 <list_iterator at 0x1040c9320>,
 <list_iterator at 0x1040c9320>]
```

Note, they are the same `list_iterator` objects...

Comment: Ah this is clear. Although I think this 'clever' use of iterator in Grouper function is really bad programming. it's clever but not very clear code.

Comment: @user1008636 I guess, athough, it relies on clearly documented behavior, I'm not sure why you would consider it bad programming. I think if you are familiar with the iterator protocol and iterators in general it is clear enough.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for that great detailed explaination